# Issue listing directory contents in linux as non-root user

Tags: linux, docker, shell, permissions, ls

I am executing script through docker container as non-root user.
Inside script creating a directory **"/var/lib/user/flags/"** using `mkdir -p /var/lib/user/flags`.
Changed the permission of directory to allow full access using `chown -R user:user /var/lib/user/flags`
Using touch command created file inside `/var/lib/user/flags`
For debugging added `ls -ltr /var/lib/user/flags` inside script where the output displays the file with correct user and group permissions,but when browsing the directory the file is not present.
Need that the file must be available at the target folder.

Thank you

Comment: I am quite sure `mkdir -p /var/lib/user/flags` was giving you a clue.

Comment: The directory is created, the ls -ltr dir debug command inside script  did show the file created. But when doing exec inside container to the dir, the file is not visible, its an empty directory.

Comment: Debug logs from shell script:

` ls -l /var/lib/user/flags
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 27 13:15 force_restore_data`

Inside container as non-root (user):
`user@000fb74bd477:/$ ls -ltr var/lib/user/flags/
total 0`

Comment: is the  aforementioned  script runs as a part of `docker build`?

Comment: Yes its executes as an entrypoint cmd.

Comment: Could it be that you created the file and then a `/var` filesystem is mounted over the `/var` you created the directory and file under?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was facing has resolved. The issue was that the clickhouse server when starts/restarts deletes this flags directory specific file for performing replication, for which I went through the documentations.

Thank you for helping.